# PrestaShop 1.7 creating own module extending Ps_Facetedsearch module

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to make my own module based on PrestaShop Faceted Search module.
My goal is to add few more custom widget types to existing checkbox, radio button, and drop-down list.

is there a way to override getContent() method from Ps_Facetedsearch class to append few new options in just one spefic place in add.tpl file and do not copy paste entire tpl file to be overwritten?

Options with value >2 are the ones I am trying to add.

add.tpl file

```
<div class="col-lg-3 pull-right">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-6">{l s='Filter style:' d='Modules.Facetedsearch.Admin'}</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <select name="layered_selection_feat_{(int)$feature['id_feature']}_filter_type">
        <option value="0">{l s='Checkbox' d='Modules.Facetedsearch.Admin'}</option>
        <option value="1">{l s='Radio button' d='Modules.Facetedsearch.Admin'}</option>
        <option value="2">{l s='Drop-down list' d='Modules.Facetedsearch.Admin'}</option>
        <option value="3">{l s='Slider' d='Modules.Facetedsearch.Admin'}</option>
        <option value="4">{l s='Range slider' d='Modules.Facetedsearch.Admin'}</option>
        <option value="5">{l s='Drop-down list' d='Modules.Facetedsearch.Admin'}</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to do the same with getFacetsFromFacetedSearchFilters method from Ps_FacetedsearchFiltersConverter.php

```
    switch ((int) $facetArray['filter_type']) {
        case 0: // checkbox
            $facet->setMultipleSelectionAllowed(true);
            $facet->setWidgetType('checkboxes');
            break;
        case 1: // radio
            $facet->setMultipleSelectionAllowed(false);
            $facet->setWidgetType('radio-buttons');
            break;
        case 2: // drop down
            $facet->setMultipleSelectionAllowed(false);
            $facet->setWidgetType('dropdown');
            break;
        case 3: // slider
            $facet->setMultipleSelectionAllowed(false);
            $facet->setWidgetType('slider');
            break;
        case 4: // rangeslider
            $facet->setMultipleSelectionAllowed(false);
            $facet->setWidgetType('rangeslider');
            break;
        case 5: // drop down
            $facet->setMultipleSelectionAllowed(false);
            $facet->setWidgetType('reangesliderex');
            break;
    }
```

I be really glad for any kind of support.

Comment: Hi, there is an heavy refactoring being done right now (see https://github.com/PrestaShop/ps_facetedsearch/pull/52)
I think you can look at how it's being done or wait for it to be done, it's supposed to make things simpler ;)

Comment: Hi @downquark Any change you got solution for this ?